# KIWI IRC: How to log chats?

Tags: irc, kiwi-irc

For using IRC, I'm using KIWI IRC as it is not possible to install MIRC or any other installable program.

The link/documentation can be found here: https://kiwiirc.com/

However, I cannot find how to log chats, I'm not sure if it is even possible.
So my questions are:

- Is it possible to log chats?
- If so, how to enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Kiwi IRC Privacy Policy](https://kiwiirc.com/privacy):

> Your IRC traffic is **never** logged. Not even to kiwiirc.com servers. This ensures that no matter who asks or who looks, the IRC traffic can not be read elsewhere.

The only logging information I can see in the source code is error logs.

Comment: Ok, I mussed have missed that (looking only at the 'features'), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Kiwi IRC does make an IRC bouncer (kiwibnc) which can be configured to log messages, although its documentation is a little sparse:

- https://github.com/kiwiirc/kiwibnc

Another bouncer that's been around a long while is ZNC:

- https://wiki.znc.in/Installation

And here's a list of other IRC bouncers (and other clients and tools too):

- https://ircv3.net/software/clients

Lastly, here's some more info on network bouncers generally:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_(software)

Hope this helps!